# How to upload file directly from a server to Google Drive using the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

Suppose I want to write a tool which allows the user to copy a file from Dropbox to Google Drive but I don't want to download the file first to my server and then upload it to the drive. Is there a way where I can insert a file to drive by just providing a URL? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Having said that, it isn't necessary to create a file on your server. You can buffer the content in memory.

Comment: What if the file size is huge? If multiple users are using the service for huge files at the same time, the server might run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could send the access token to the client via a POST request. You'd have to encrypt it, of course, preferably SSL. Then the client could use the Drive SDK to upload the file directly from itself, completely bypassing your server.

Comment: That's the question, how to upload using URL because I can't find how to do that in Drive API documents.