# How to upload a PDF file from a system in ajax url POST method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, google-drive-api

I just uploaded an empty PDF file into google drive using its API, on click of a button.

```
<html>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){## Heading ##
enter code here
          $.ajax({

            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'http://fddf3e6.ngrok.io/untitle.pdf',
            contentType: 'application/pdf',
            success: function() { 
console.log('Successfully File uploaded!'); 
},
            error: function() { 
console.log('Error while uploading file!!!'); 
},
            beforeSend: function(xhr) 
{

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <accessToken>');

      }

          });

        });

      });

</script>

<button>Send</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I gave the URL of the PDF file location as data object but it took the URL as just a content of the PDF file. How to upload a PDF file into google Drive which is assigned by me.

Now I'm able to upload a empty PDF file into drive by having the user access token and google drive API. I just need help to select a PDF file which I want to upload. how can I select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284414/5995040), you cannot upload a file using a url. You can buffer the content in memory then upload it.

You can use this code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34848574/5995040) to get the content of the file.

```
var base64Data = btoa(e.target.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' +
          base64Data + close_delim;

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart',
          type: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/related; boundary="'+ boundary + '"'
          },
          success: function() {
            // TODO XIN
            console.log('>>> DONE');
          },
          error: _handleUploadErrors,
          data: multipartRequestBody,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          crossDomain: true
        });
```

You can also set the upload type to match what type of file you are uploading.

> - Simple upload: **`uploadType=media`**. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less). To perform a simple upload, refer to [Performing a Simple Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload).
> - Multipart upload: **`uploadType=multipart`**. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in a single request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to [Performing a Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload).
> - Resumable upload: **`uploadType=resumable`**. For more reliable transfer, especially important with large files. Resumable uploads are a good choice for most applications, since they also work for small files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload. To perform a resumable upload, refer to [Performing a Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload).

Hope it helps.